# How to change the default tab while navigating in Flutter?

Tags: tabs, flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code for the TabBar page:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  static String tag = 'home-page';

  @override
  _homepage createState() => new _homepage();
}

class _homepage extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{


  AnimationController percentageAnimationController;
  TabController _tabController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);


    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(

        bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: new TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: Theme.Colors.loginGradientStart,
              labelColor: Theme.Colors.loginGradientStart,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                new Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(wind_icon),
                ),
                new Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(chart_icon),
                ),
                new Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(settings_icon),
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
        body:
        new TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[

            TabOne(),

            TabTwo(),

            TabThree(),

            ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now if I navigate to this page it automatically opens the first tab but I want to open the second tab instead of the first i.e. tab index 1.

I am able to find out that we can achieve this by using     **_tabController.animateTo(1);**
 but I want to know how can I do this from button press of other pages.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can Use Initial Index:

```
_tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. I created a file named "globals.dart".

**my_app/globals.dart**

```
library my_app.globals;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TabController tabController;
```

And, after you set the tab controller, copy reference to this.

**_homepage Class**

```
import 'package:my_app/globals.dart' as globals;

@override
void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

    globals.tabController = _tabController;

    super.initState();
}
```

**other_page Class**

```
import 'package:my_app/globals.dart' as globals;

...(in any function you want)...

globals.tabController.animateTo(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

At this moment, if you don't need to expose the controller for other reasons and are using `DefaultTabController`, you can use the class [initialIndex property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController/initialIndex.html) :

```
DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 1,
        child: ...
```

You can check a DartPad demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1b661ddd1104e9cf4a26174c6f6c83a9)

Comment: When my page containing the `DefaultTabControl` rebuilds, it does not show the `initialIndex` property I specify when it changes value. It only shows the **initial** value as it was originally set.

Comment: @oravecz I'm not sure if I understood what you mean, but you can use a variable to persist a value, if necessary.

Comment: I was having the same issue as @oravecz but it worked when I created the ```TabController``` like this: ```TabController(vsync: this, length: 2, initialIndex: initIndex);```