# How to Set Initial Tab in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

[image: here is image for proper idea]

I want that whenever I run my application, it should be moved to Tab A, but by default it is moving to first tab, which is named tab B.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Tab Bar"),
              bottom:
                  TabBar(tabs: [Tab(child: Text('B')), Tab(child: Text('A'))]),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: [
              Center(
                child: Text("this is to be second tab"),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text("this is to be first tab"),
              ),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: initialIndex maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941366/how-to-change-the-default-tab-while-navigating-in-flutter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DefaultTabController` has an `initialIndex` property which is set to `0` by default.

In your case, since you have two `Tab`s, you would need to set the `initialIndex` property to `1`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          // set initial index to 1
          initialIndex: 1,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Tab Bar"),
              bottom:
                  TabBar(tabs: [Tab(child: Text('B')), Tab(child: Text('A'))]),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: [
              Center(
                child: Text("this is to be second tab"),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text("this is to be first tab"),
              ),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx sir  this is working fine but i have one more issue like we reach to tab A and from tab A to if i swipe left then it would be navigate to different screen and also if we re-return in Tab A and from tab A if i swipe right then it is going to tab B good but if i swipe right again from tab b then it will be navigate to different screen